# JQuery: Ckeditor and autosuggestion not working together in one page?

Tags: jquery

```
     <script type="text/javascript"src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/auto/auto.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/auto/jquery.tagin.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/auto/jquery.tagin.css">

     <script>
        jquery(document).ready(function(){
            jquery('input#tags').tagin({availableTags['C++','PHP','Python','Java','JavaScript','Ruby','HTML','Perl','Drupal','Wordpress','Magento','Joomla','Jquery'];});});
     </script>
     <script src="js/jquery1.11.1.min.js"type="text/javascript"language="javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
     <link href="css/editor.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <script src="js/editor.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

     <div id="txtEditor"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          jquery(document).ready(function()
             {
              jquery("#txtEditor").Editor();
             });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code multiple jQuery or jquery-ui become problematic:

```
     <script src="js/jquery1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/auto/auto.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/auto/jquery.tagin.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/auto/jquery.tagin.css">

     <script>
        jquery(document).ready(function(){
            jquery('input#tags').tagin({availableTags['C++','PHP','Python','Java','JavaScript','Ruby','HTML','Perl','Drupal','Wordpress','Magento','Joomla','Jquery'];});});
     </script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
     <link href="css/editor.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <script src="js/editor.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

     <div id="txtEditor"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          jquery(document).ready(function()
             {
              jquery("#txtEditor").Editor();
             });
      </script>
```

Try this.